# JQuery Toggle Divs Based On Index not retoggle when clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

and thank you for reading this question.  Let me preface this by saying that I am not a programmer and only have tried to learn javascript to make my own websites look and function the way I want.

I have a page with several hidden divs.  I'm using  elements with the same class and different targets to trigger this Jquery

```
jQuery(function () {
jQuery('.nav').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index(),
        newTarget = jQuery('.targetDiv').eq(index);
    jQuery('.targetDiv').not(newTarget).slideUp('fast')
    newTarget.delay('fast').slideToggle('fast')
    return false;
  })
});
```

So my ".targetDiv"s look like this:

```
<div class=".targetDiv" style="display:none">div1</div>
<div class=".targetDiv" style="display:none">div2</div>
<div class=".targetDiv" style="display:none">div3</div>
```

And the "navigation" would look something like this

```
<a href="#" class=".nav" target="1">link1</a>
<a href="#" class=".nav" target="2">link2</a>
<a href="#" class=".nav" target="3">link3</a>
```

This is not my code, and I got it from here:  http://forum.jquery.com/topic/slidetoggle-multiple-divs-31-5-2013

It works exactly as it is supposed to and I have no complaints about that.  When you click on a link, the corresponding div toggles, but when you click the same div again right afterwards, it toggles again and slides up (which is how the code is written).  I want to stop that from happening, and since I am new to Javascript and Jquery I can't figure out how to do it.  My non programmer mind assumes that there should be some kind of if else clause, where you would say:

if .targetDiv is :visible, then do not toggle newTarget.  However when I tried to do that, it did not work.

```
if($(".targetDiv").is(":hidden")) {     jQuery(function () {
jQuery('.nav').click(function () {
    var index = $(this).index(),
        newTarget = jQuery('.targetDiv').eq(index);
    jQuery('.targetDiv').not(newTarget).slideUp('fast')
    newTarget.delay('fast').slideToggle('fast')
    return false;
  })
});} 

else {alert("already open")}
```

I don't know how else I should handle this, but it must be possible and I am probably just thinking of how to achieve what I want in entirely the wrong way.  I understand very little about javascript, but I am not asking for someone to write this for me, I'd rather have someone tell me what it is that I am doing that is incorrect, then explain what it is I should be trying to do.  Then I can use google to search for the way to achieve that.

Again, thank you for taking the time to read this and hopefully I've been detailed enough for some answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap the two 'slide' lines in the if statement, like so:

```
if (!newTarget.is(':visible'))
{
    jQuery('.targetDiv').not(newTarget).slideUp('fast');
    newTarget.delay('fast').slideToggle('fast');
}
```

You may also want to fix a few issues with the html, e.g. take the periods out of your class names.  When querying for DOM elements, the "." means, "Find the things that have a class called *_*[whatever follows the dot]".  Don't put dots in the classes themselves.

You may also want to take out the `href` attributes of the `<a>` tags.  They aren't necessary.

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xf0judv6/)'s a working JSFiddle.  Cheers!

Comment: My apologies, my html actually doesn't have "."s in the class, that was a silly accident that I overlooked when typing up the question.  Regardless  The answer worked perfectly, so thank you for that!